# MultiValue Parameter not working when using to filter dataset from oracle database

Tags: reporting-services

I am creating the SSRS report connecting with oracle DB. I am using the multivalued parameter to filter the data from the oracle query. Query is as below:-

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME F WHERE F.Region IN (
SELECT
  TRIM(regexp_substr(:Region, '[^,]+', 1,  LEVEL ))
FROM
  dual
 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(:Region,  ' ' ) + 1)
```

I tested this query directly in Oracle database by passing some hardcoded value in the :Region and its working well but the query using the parameter name is not working.

I followed this link too but still no luck.

Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: I guess the link in your question is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the way to filter the data. Instead of adding the paramaters list in the dataset. I have added the filters parameters to the tablix properties and helped me to filter the data based upon the parameter selection.